# Return true/false based on specific text from multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have sheet file with 2 sheets.

**First sheet:**

> Cell that should contain formula I am trying to make

**Second sheet:**

> 2 columns with 15 rows each, where each cell can be blank or contain one of 3 predefined values (Good, Bad, Missing).

**What formula should provide:**
If any (not just all) of the cells from the second sheet contains Bad or Missing, display True in the cell on the first sheet, otherwise display False.

I have tried multiple formulae with `regexmatch`, `istext`... but none works for cell range. I know how to use `regexmatch` when I have one cell to inspect, but when I have multiple cells and when the question is "do any of the cells contain specific text, but not necessarily all", I get confused...

Simplified example:

[image: example of issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest that Countif is the way to go to count how many instances there are of "Bad" or Missing":

```
=countif(Sheet2!B3:C17,"Bad")+countif(Sheet2!B3:C17,"Missing")
```

Then if you want to report this as TRUE if the result is more than zero or FALSE if not, you would need to alter it to:

```
=(countif(Sheet2!B3:C17,"Bad")+countif(Sheet2!B3:C17,"Missing"))>0
```

Note

Outer brackets are not necesssary in above formula because <,> etc. have lowest precedence, but may improve readability.

Alternative:

```
=countif(Sheet2!B3:C17,"Bad")+countif(Sheet2!B3:C17,"Missing")>0
```

Comment: It does work. Thank you so much :)

Can you by any chance modify that formula if i want to show custom labels instead of true / false as well?

Comment: You're very welcome. Yes, you could put it in an If statement like =if(countif(Sheet2!B3:C17,"Bad")+countif(Sheet2!B3:C17,"Missing"),"Issues","No Issues")

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Sheet2!A3:A), 
 IF(((Sheet2!B3:B="bad")+(Sheet2!B3:B="missing"))* 
    ((Sheet2!C3:C="bad")+(Sheet2!C3:C="missing")), TRUE, FALSE), ))
```

[image: 0]